# Code style in using argument names

Tags: python, arguments, pep8

What's the recommended style for argument names?

```
open(file='myfile.txt')
```

or

```
open('myfile.txt')
```

[PEP8 Style Guide For Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) doesn't mention anything about this. When do I use one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit I see in using explicit names is that the modification of a function's signature will have less impact on code relying on it.

For instance, say you're using a module's function, defined as:

```
their_function(a, b, c=1)
```

You're calling it with the `c` keyword argument by:

```
their_function(myA, myB, myC)
```

But now, the module's developers find it useful to have another keyword argument, and in their mind, it makes more sense that it comes before `c`.
So now, the function is:

```
their_function(a, b, d=2, c=1)
```

Everywhere you call `their_function(myA, myB, myC)`, now `myC` is passed to `their_function` as `d`, and everything is messed up.

On the other hand, had you called it by `their_function(myA, myB, c=myC)`, the mapping of the keyword arguments would have been so that `myC` would have still been passed to `their_function` as `c`.

Of course, this is probably overkill for obvious functions, such as `print` or `open` whose, positional argument is natural.
But I find it really reassuring to call `open(path, 'r', encoding='utf8')`, rather than `open(path, 'r', 'utf8')`, because even if I got the order wrong, the behaviour would still be as expected.

---

As for me, except in a few cases where it would be counter-intuitive, I tend to force the use of the names for the keyword arguments.

Python 3, from some version on, allows you to do the following:

```
def my_function(a, b, *, c=1):
    pass
```

Here, the use of the splat operator `*` alone tells Python that no positional argument can be found after the third one.
This will result in a `TypeError` when passing a fourth argument as a positional one, ie without naming it.

```
>>> my_function(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: my_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

>>> my_function(1, 2)
# OK

>>> my_function(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: my_function() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

>>> my_function(1, 2, c=3)
# OK
```

This helps you make your code a little more fool-proof, especially when defining functions with many positional or keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get different opinions. Personally I would argue that using keyword arguments whenever possible is *strictly better* because it attaches human readable semantics to a function call. The reader has a decent shot at guessing what the arguments are supposed to be without inspecting the code/docs any further.

However, I do sometimes omit the keyword(s) when using well-known functions.